# How do I write data to file without single quote?

Tags: python

I have written a code where I want my data to file exactly as it is but padding spaces.

No delimiter should be there in file.

Data need to be read from this file, `A.txt`:

```
a;j;kk
gh;jsk;kk;
gsh;kks;jj
```

Expected output in file:

```
     a        j        kk
    gh        jsk        kk
    gsh       kks        jj
```

My main motive is to get data with padding in file and should not have any delimiter or single quote.

My code:

```
import csv as cv

md=''

with open(r'C:\\Desktop\\A.txt',mode='r') as file:
    
    csvFile = cv.reader(file)
     
    for i in csvFile:
        
        md = md + (i[0].rjust(10))
        md = md + (i[1].rjust(10))
        md = md + (i[2].rjust(10)) 

        result = md 
       
        with open(r'C:\\Desktop\\B.txt',mode='w') as file:
             
             cw = cv.writer(file)
             
             cw.writerow(result)
        
        md =''
        result=''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `print` and `f-strings` to get the expected result:

```
import csv

with (open('A.txt', 'r') as fpa,
      open('B.txt', 'w') as fpb):
    reader = csv.reader(fpa, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        print(' '*10, *[f'{val:10}' for val in row], sep='', file=fpb)
```

Output `B.txt`:

```
          a         j         kk        
          gh        jsk       kk                  
          gsh       kks       jj
```

Comment: : I want to add spaces in front

Comment: You can also rjust with: `print(*[f'{val:>10}' for val in row], sep='', file=fpb)`